# How to run a shell start linux os?

Tags: linux, shell

i want to know how to configure shell script auto run on linux os. i created

> 'test.sh' script file

and than i tried two ways

The first way was

> bin/bash /home/user/test.sh or bin/sh /home/user/test.sh in rc.local file

and the second way was

> /usr/share/application/test.background and /ect/xdc/startup/test.backgrou

this is not ok. How do I do this? i am using ubuntu

Comment: I edited your question. Please look, if it is correct. If not use the `edit` link below the question and revert to your previous version.

Comment: The `/bin/bash` should start with a `/`, and you might `chmod u+x` your script file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a script at boot time, you copy your script to the `/etc/init.d` directory, make it executable

```
chmod a+x /etc/init.d/test.sh
```

and then link it to the appropriate run levels with

```
update-rc.d test.sh defaults
```

Your script should have the following structure

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
start)
    # this is run at startup
    echo "Starting script test.sh"
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
stop)
    # this is run at shutdown
    echo "Stopping script test.sh"
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/test.sh {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

See also [SystemAdministration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SystemAdministration) and [UpstartHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto) for details.